# equivalent norm on $C^2([0,1])$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory

I would like to know if the norm 
$$\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\infty}+ \left\lVert f' \right\rVert_{\infty}+\left\lVert f'' \right\rVert_{\infty}$$
is equivalent to the norm
$$\left\lVert f \right\rVert_{\infty}+\left\lVert f'' \right\rVert_{\infty}$$

on $C^2([0,1])$

It is clear to me that the only non-trivial question is whether we can bound $f'$ in terms of $f$ and $f''.$

Comment: What have you tried to solve this problem? Can you think of ways you might show norm equivalence or inequivalence?

Comment: well, the only non-trivial thing is the question if we can bound the sup of the first derivative in terms of the sup of $f$ and $f''$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an equality you can use to get started: apply the fundamental theorem of calculus twice. If $x,y \in [0,1]$ then $$f'(x) = f'(y) + \int_x^y f''(t) \, dt.$$ Now integrate with respect to $y$ from $0$ to $1$ to get $$f'(x) = f(1) - f(0) + \int_0^1 \int_x^y f''(t) \, dt dy.$$